# wxWidgets: wxString::wxString(int) private within this context

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have a subclass of wxHtmlListBox called TestClass, but I get the error:

> /usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/string.h:682:0 /usr/include/wx-2.8/wx/string.h:682: error: 'wxString::wxString(int)' is private
>   MainFrame.cpp:106:0 MainFrame.cpp:106: error: within this context

MainFrame.cpp line 106 is this:

```
TestClass *tc = new TestClass(this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, 
                              wxDefaultSize, NULL, wxBORDER_DEFAULT);
```

The files for TestClass can be found at http://cl.ly/1VSo

Any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing wxBORDER_DEFAULT into a const wxString reference:

```
TestClass(
    wxWindow* parent, // this
    wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY, // wxID_ANY
    const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, // wxDefaultPosition
    const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize, // wxDefaultSize
    long style = 0, // NULL
    const wxString& name = wxHtmlListBoxNameStr ); // wxBORDER_DEFAULT
```

...but `wxBORDER_DEFAULT` is part of an enum (essentially an integer):

```
enum wxBorder
{
    /*  this is different from wxBORDER_NONE as by default the controls do have */
    /*  border */
    wxBORDER_DEFAULT = 0,

    wxBORDER_NONE   = 0x00200000,
    wxBORDER_STATIC = 0x01000000,
    wxBORDER_SIMPLE = 0x02000000,
    wxBORDER_RAISED = 0x04000000,
    wxBORDER_SUNKEN = 0x08000000,
    wxBORDER_DOUBLE = 0x10000000, /* deprecated */
    wxBORDER_THEME =  0x10000000,

    /*  a mask to extract border style from the combination of flags */
    wxBORDER_MASK   = 0x1f200000
};
```

So it's using the constructor you mentioned for a wxString:

```
wxString::wxString(int)
```

...which is private and hence you're getting an error. Try passing in a string or NULL instead :-)

Comment: Thanks, I can't believe I missed that.  This and Thomas's answer below both worked great.

Answer (score 2):

Your line 106 does not match the constructor for TestClass, especially the last parameter / argument:

```
TestClass(wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id = wxID_ANY, const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize, long style = 0, const wxString& name = wxHtmlListBoxNameStr);
```

The `TestClass` wants a string, not a border style.